# Acknowledgements footnote

Tags: symbols, footnotes

I am trying to get a * instead of an arabic numeral for my acknowledgements footnote. I am using the template that the conference organizers provided and for some reason neither `\author` nor `\thanks` seem to work.

I have tried the following but it changes all the footnotes from numerals to symbols (and I only want the first one to be an *).

```
\renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
```

I have also tried using `footmisc` with the `symbol*` option but I run into the same problem.

Many thanks.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Put `\setcounter{footnote}{0}\renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}` just after that footnote.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The rude way is to group the redefinition of `\thefootnote` with braces to keep it local. In this case you must reset the counter at the end of the group, otherwise the first regular footnote will be numbered with `2` (or more if there are more thanks).

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
{% begin group
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}% set smybols
Introduction\footnote{Thank you, Jone Doe!}
\setcounter{footnote}{0}% set footnote counter back to 0
}% end group

Main text\footnote{Regular note.}
\end{document}
```

Although this works, I recommend not to use it. If the template doesn’t provide it it is likely that the format doesn’t allows it ;-)

Comment: Thanks a lot. This worked really nicely, although you are probably right. I should not make the conference organizers' lives more complicated :-)

Comment: @Helena: Your welcome :-) you may like to [mark my answer as accepted](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852). That will bring some reputation to both of us ;-) …